# IIS Change Physical Directory in DevOps

Tags: iis, azure-devops, asp.net-core-webapi, devops

I have a release pipeline where i am deploying my .Net Core Web API by using FTP. This works when the folder is empty, but when the .Net Core Web API is running i cannot overwrite the files without downtime and stopping the application. What i then want to do is having two identical directories, so when i deploy to one folder, the IIS switches to point on the backup directory. What i am wondering about is if this is possible to do programatically in DevOps, or do i have to change physical path manually?

Comment: That would not prevent downtime.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying a web application by using FTP would cause the issue of overriding the files in use when the website is online.
On my side, I prefer to use the below task to manage the IIS website and deploy the web application to IIS.
[image]
Select the `Create or Update` action will automatically create a website or update an existing website, which is implemented by `IIS APPCMD API`.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe
Here is the official documentation of the IIS Web Application Manage/Deploy website task.
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroupV0/README.md
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroupV0/README.md
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. This seem interesting and i have had a look at it, but my website is running on an external IIS-server. Is it possible to connect that one with this task? How? :)

Comment: It is easy to deploy that project to the actual machine as long as we have registered the remote machine as a client proxy or executing a deployment group job, by which we can specify the machine executing the deployment job. on my side, I specify a deployment group job, In the property of the Deployment group job, I have to specify which machine the deployment group is made of. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bjwW.png   check the below link for more, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops.